# Load javascript than parse the source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to parse a source from a other webspace. The problem is that the other webspace loads the news with javascript. And every code here on Stackoverflow or Google parse the source before the news is loadet

I know it doesn't work with php therefore I tryed it with jquery, without success.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $.ajax({
         url: 'https://www.habbo.com/',
         success: function(data){
             $("#textarea").val(data);
         }
 })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea style="width:100%; height:900px;" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Here is the result that I want get:

```
<html ng-app="app" lang="de"><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style><style id="stndz-style">div[class*="item-container-obpd"], a[data-redirect*="paid.outbrain.com"], a[onmousedown*="paid.outbrain.com"] { display: none !important; } a div[class*="item-container-ad"] { height: 0px !important; overflow: hidden !important; position: absolute !important; } div[data-item-syndicated="true"] { display: none !important; } .grv_is_sponsored { display: none !important; } .zergnet-widget-related { display: none !important; } </style><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="robots" content="NOODP"><title>Finde Freunde, hab Spass und werde bemerkt! - Habbo</title><meta name="description" content="Registriere dich GRATIS im grössten virtuellen Hotel weltweit! Triff und finde Freunde spiele Spiele, chatte mit anderen, erstelle deinen Avatar, entwerfe Räume und mehr..."><meta property="og:type" content="website"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Habbo"><meta property="og:title" content="Finde Freunde, hab Spass und werde bemerkt!"><meta property="og:description" content="Registriere dich GRATIS im grössten virtuellen Hotel weltweit! Triff und finde Freunde spiele Spiele, chatte mit anderen, erstelle deinen Avatar, entwerfe Räume und mehr..."><meta property="og:url" content="https://www.habbo.de/" habbo-head-url="content"><meta property="og:image" content="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_summary_image-1200x628.85a9f5dc.png"><meta property="og:image:height" content="628"><meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta name="twitter:title" content="Finde Freunde, hab Spass und werde bemerkt!"><meta name="twitter:description" content="Registriere dich GRATIS im grössten virtuellen Hotel weltweit! Triff und finde Freunde spiele Spiele, chatte mit anderen, erstelle deinen Avatar, entwerfe Räume und mehr..."><meta name="twitter:image" content="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_summary_image-1200x628.85a9f5dc.png"><meta name="twitter:site" content="@De_Habbo"><meta itemprop="name" content="Finde Freunde, hab Spass und werde bemerkt!"><meta itemprop="description" content="Registriere dich GRATIS im grössten virtuellen Hotel weltweit! Triff und finde Freunde spiele Spiele, chatte mit anderen, erstelle deinen Avatar, entwerfe Räume und mehr..."><meta itemprop="image" content="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_summary_image-1200x628.85a9f5dc.png"><meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=794866182"><meta name="fragment" content="!"><meta name="revision" content="9661fe6"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"><meta name="prerender-status-code" prerender-status-code="" content="200"><meta name="prerender-header" prerender-header="" content="Location: https://www.habbo.de/hotel"><link rel="canonical" href="https://www.habbo.de/" habbo-head-url="href"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/favicon.08c747be.ico"><link rel="icon" sizes="196x196" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_icon-196x196.42aab784.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_icon-60x60-precomposed.99edad69.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_icon-76x76-precomposed.e106f3ac.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_icon-120x120-precomposed.18320473.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/app_icon-152x152-precomposed.b6728e86.png"><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://www.habbo.de/rss.xml" title="Habbo News"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-l10n/de.json"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/sprite.541175ea.png"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/sprite@2x.2c5de56d.png" media="(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi), (min-resolution: 2dppx)"><link rel="prefetch" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/assets/images/backgrounds/hotel.ba57eb56.png"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web/america/de/app.228084b6.css"><script async="" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js"></script><script src="https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js?hash=47eba3f4bdde48bbb7044ef343f2acbd&amp;ua=modern_es6" async="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/linkid.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ecommerce.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" defer="" async="" src="//trck.spoteffects.net/analytics/spef.min.js"></script><script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script>window.prerenderReady=!1</script><meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"><script>window.session=null;window.geoLocation={"country":"ch","continent":"eu"};window.partnerCodeInfo=null;window.systemData={"open":true};</script><style type="text/css">.fb_hidden{position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}.fb_reposition{overflow:hidden;position:relative}.fb_invisible{display:none}.fb_reset{background:none;border:0;border-spacing:0;color:#000;cursor:auto;direction:ltr;font-family:"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:1;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;text-indent:0;text-shadow:none;text-transform:none;visibility:visible;white-space:normal;word-spacing:normal}.fb_reset>div{overflow:hidden}@keyframes fb_transform{from{opacity:0;transform:scale(.95)}to{opacity:1;transform:scale(1)}}.fb_animate{animation:fb_transform .3s forwards}
.fb_dialog{background:rgba(82, 82, 82, .7);position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}.fb_dialog_advanced{border-radius:8px;padding:10px}.fb_dialog_content{background:#fff;color:#373737}.fb_dialog_close_icon{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;cursor:pointer;display:block;height:15px;position:absolute;right:18px;top:17px;width:15px}.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{left:5px;right:auto;top:5px}.fb_dialog_padding{background-color:transparent;position:absolute;width:1px;z-index:-1}.fb_dialog_close_icon:hover{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -15px transparent}.fb_dialog_close_icon:active{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -30px transparent}.fb_dialog_iframe{line-height:0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title{background:#6d84b4;border:1px solid #365899;color:#fff;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin:0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title>span{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yd/r/Cou7n-nqK52.gif) no-repeat 5px 50%;float:left;padding:5px 0 7px 26px}body.fb_hidden{height:100%;left:0;margin:0;overflow:visible;position:absolute;top:-10000px;transform:none;width:100%}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ya/r/3rhSv5V8j3o.gif) white no-repeat 50% 50%;min-height:100%;min-width:100%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;z-index:10001}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered{background:none;height:auto;min-height:initial;min-width:initial;width:auto}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered #fb_dialog_loader_spinner{width:100%}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered .fb_dialog_content{background:none}.loading.centered #fb_dialog_loader_close{clear:both;color:#fff;display:block;font-size:18px;padding-top:20px}#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);bottom:0;left:0;min-height:100%;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:100%;z-index:10000}#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay.hidden{display:none}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading iframe{visibility:hidden}.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_iframe{position:sticky;top:0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header{background:linear-gradient(from(#738aba), to(#2c4987));border-bottom:1px solid;border-color:#1d3c78;box-shadow:white 0 1px 1px -1px inset;color:#fff;font:bold 14px Helvetica, sans-serif;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0;vertical-align:middle;white-space:nowrap}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header table{height:43px;width:100%}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_left{font-size:12px;padding-left:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_right{font-size:12px;padding-right:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px}.fb_dialog_content .touchable_button{background:linear-gradient(from(#4267B2), to(#2a4887));background-clip:padding-box;border:1px solid #29487d;border-radius:3px;display:inline-block;line-height:18px;margin-top:3px;max-width:85px;padding:4px 12px;position:relative}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .touchable_button input{background:none;border:none;color:#fff;font:bold 12px Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:2px -12px;padding:2px 6px 3px 6px;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .header_center{color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;line-height:18px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_content{background:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;border:1px solid #4a4a4a;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;height:150px}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_footer{background:#f5f6f7;border:1px solid #4a4a4a;border-top-color:#ccc;height:40px}#fb_dialog_loader_close{float:left}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_button{text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{visibility:hidden}#fb_dialog_loader_spinner{animation:rotateSpinner 1.2s linear infinite;background-color:transparent;background-image:url(https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yD/r/t-wz8gw1xG1.png);background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:24px;width:24px}@keyframes rotateSpinner{0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}
.fb_iframe_widget{display:inline-block;position:relative}.fb_iframe_widget span{display:inline-block;position:relative;text-align:justify}.fb_iframe_widget iframe{position:absolute}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop,.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop span,.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop iframe{max-width:100%}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid_desktop iframe{min-width:220px;position:relative}.fb_iframe_widget_lift{z-index:1}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid{display:inline}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span{width:100%}</style><link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.ch/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.habbo.de" as="script"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.ch/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.habbo.de"></script><link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.habbo.de" as="script"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.habbo.de"></script><script src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2019052302.js" async=""></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d3hmp0045zy3cs.cloudfront.net/HEAD/providers.css" type="text/css"></head><body habbo-client-disable-scrollbars="" class="" style=""><!----><div class="content" ui-view="" style=""><!----><habbo-header-small ng-if="!HomeController.hasHeaderLarge()" active="home"><habbo-header-ad><!----><div ng-if="HeaderAdController.hasAd" class="header-ad"><habbo-ad-unit unit="leaderboard" class="header-ad__ad"><!----><habbo-ad-double-click ng-if="AdUnitController.hasAds() &amp;&amp; !AdUnitController.isAdsPrevented()" unit="leaderboard"><div id="div-gpt-ad-2" ng-dfp-ad="div-gpt-ad-2" translation="Drittanbieter-Anzeige" class="ad-double-click"></div></habbo-ad-double-click><!----></habbo-ad-unit></div><!----></habbo-header-ad><header class="header__wrapper wrapper"><a href="/" class="header__habbo__logo"><h1 class="header__habbo__name" id="ga-linkid-habbo">Habbo</h1></a><!----><habbo-user-menu habbo-require-session="" class="header__aside header__aside--user-menu"><div ng-init="toggle = false;" habbo-false-on-outside-click="toggle" class="user-menu"><div class="user-menu__header"><a ng-click="toggle = !toggle;" class="user-menu__toggle"><div class="user-menu__name__wrapper"><div class="user-menu__name" ng-class="{ 'user-menu__name--open': toggle }">BartTotal</div></div><habbo-imager figure="hr-3525-35.hd-195-1.ch-878-82-84.lg-3320-64-1408.sh-3068-91-1320.fa-3276-72.cc-3389-82-91" name="BartTotal" size="bighead" class="user-menu__avatar"><img ng-src="/habbo-imaging/avatar/hr-3525-35.hd-195-1.ch-878-82-84.lg-3320-64-1408.sh-3068-91-1320.fa-3276-72.cc-3389-82-91%2Cs-2.g-1.d-2.h-2.a-0%2C1e6e6045462e928513b1c88f6533a00a.png" ng-srcset="/habbo-imaging/avatar/hr-3525-35.hd-195-1.ch-878-82-84.lg-3320-64-1408.sh-3068-91-1320.fa-3276-72.cc-3389-82-91%2Cs-2.g-1.d-2.h-2.a-0%2C1e6e6045462e928513b1c88f6533a00a.png 1x" ng-style="{ 'min-width': ImagerController.dimensions.width }" alt="BartTotal" width="54" height="62" class="imager" src="/habbo-imaging/avatar/hr-3525-35.hd-195-1.ch-878-82-84.lg-3320-64-1408.sh-3068-91-1320.fa-3276-72.cc-3389-82-91%2Cs-2.g-1.d-2.h-2.a-0%2C1e6e6045462e928513b1c88f6533a00a.png" srcset="/habbo-imaging/avatar/hr-3525-35.hd-195-1.ch-878-82-84.lg-3320-64-1408.sh-3068-91-1320.fa-3276-72.cc-3389-82-91%2Cs-2.g-1.d-2.h-2.a-0%2C1e6e6045462e928513b1c88f6533a00a.png 1x" style="min-width: 54px;"></habbo-imager></a></div><ul ng-hide="!toggle" class="user-menu__list ng-hide"><li class="user-menu__item"><a ng-href="/profile/BartTotal" ng-class="{ 'user-menu__link--active': UserMenuController.isMyProfileActive() }" class="user-menu__link user-menu__link--profile" translate="NAVIGATION_PROFILE" href="/profile/BartTotal">Profil ansehen</a></li><li class="user-menu__item"><a href="/settings" ng-class="{ 'user-menu__link--active': UserMenuController.isSettingsActive() }" class="user-menu__link user-menu__link--settings" translate="NAVIGATION_SETTINGS">Einstellungen</a></li><li class="user-menu__item"><a ng-href="https://habbohelpde.zendesk.com/home" class="user-menu__link user-menu__link--help" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" translate="NAVIGATION_HELP" href="https://habbohelpde.zendesk.com/home">Hilfe</a></li><li class="user-menu__item"><a ng-click="UserMenuController.logout()" class="user-menu__link user-menu__link--logout" translate="NAVIGATION_LOGOUT">Logout</a></li></ul></div></habbo-user-menu><!----><!----></header><habbo-navigation active="home"><nav class="navigation"><ul class="navigation__menu"><li class="navigation__item"><a href="/" ng-class="{ 'navigation__link--active': NavigationController.active === 'home' }" class="navigation__link navigation__link--home navigation__link--active" translate="NAVIGATION_HOME" id="ga-linkid-home">Startseite</a></li><li class="navigation__item"><a href="/community" ng-class="{ 'navigation__link--active': NavigationController.active === 'community' }" class="navigation__link navigation__link--community" translate="NAVIGATION_COMMUNITY" id="ga-linkid-community">Community</a></li><li class="navigation__item"><a href="/shop" ng-class="{ 'navigation__link--active': NavigationController.active === 'shop' }" class="navigation__link navigation__link--shop" translate="NAVIGATION_SHOP" id="ga-linkid-shop">HabboShopping</a></li><li class="navigation__item"><a href="/playing-habbo" ng-class="{ 'navigation__link--active': NavigationController.active === 'playingHabbo' }" class="navigation__link navigation__link--playing-habbo" translate="NAVIGATION_PLAYING_HABBO" id="ga-linkid-playing-habbo">Habbo spielen</a></li><!----><li habbo-require-session="" class="navigation__item navigation__item--aside navigation__item--hotel"><!----><habbo-hotel-button habbo-require-flash=""><a href="/hotel" class="hotel-button" id="ga-linkid-hotel"><span class="hotel-button__text" translate="NAVIGATION_HOTEL">Hotel</span> </a></habbo-hotel-button><!----></li><!----></ul></nav></habbo-navigation><div class="wrapper" ng-transclude=""></div></habbo-header-small><!----><!----><habbo-tabs><nav ng-hide="TabsController.tabs.length < 2" class="tabs"><!----><div ng-click="TabsController.open = !TabsController.open" class="tabs__toggle"><div ng-class="{'tabs__toggle__title--active': TabsController.open}" class="tabs__toggle__title" translate="HOME_NEWS_TAB">Was ist neu</div></div><ul class="tabs__menu ng-hide" ng-hide="!TabsController.open" ng-transclude=""><habbo-tab path="/" strict-path="true" translation-key="HOME_NEWS_TAB"><li class="tab"><a ng-href="/" ng-class="{ 'tab__link--active': TabController.active }" class="tab__link tab__link--active" translate="HOME_NEWS_TAB" href="/">Was ist neu</a></li></habbo-tab><!----><habbo-tab habbo-require-session="" path="/messaging" translation-key="HOME_MESSAGING_TAB"><li class="tab"><a ng-href="/messaging" ng-class="{ 'tab__link--active': TabController.active }" class="tab__link" translate="HOME_MESSAGING_TAB" href="/messaging">Nachrichten</a></li></habbo-tab><!----></ul></nav></habbo-tabs><!----><main class="wrapper wrapper--content" ui-view=""><!----><habbo-moderation-notification habbo-require-session=""><!----></habbo-moderation-notification><!----><section><h1 translate="NEWS_TITLE">Aktuelle News</h1><div class="main main--fixed"><habbo-compile data="NewsController.promos"><section>
    <article class="news-header news-header--column">
        <a href="/community/article/25229/diesen-monat-das-festival-der-kunste" class="news-header__link news-header__banner">
            <figure class="news-header__viewport">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_fest19_gen-2.png" alt="Diesen Monat: Das Festival der Künste!" class="news-header__image news-header__image--featured">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_fest19_gen-2_thumb.png" alt="Diesen Monat: Das Festival der Künste!" class="news-header__image news-header__image--thumbnail">
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="/community/article/25229/diesen-monat-das-festival-der-kunste" class="news-header__link news-header__wrapper">
            <h2 class="news-header__title">Diesen Monat: Das Festival der Künste!</h2>
        </a>
        <aside class="news-header__wrapper news-header__info">
            <time class="news-header__date">03.06.2019</time>
            <ul class="news-header__categories">
                <li class="news-header__category">
                    <a href="/community/category/campaigns-activities" class="news-header__category__link" translate="NEWS_CATEGORY_CAMPAIGNS_ACTIVITIES">Kampagnen &amp; Aktivitäten</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <p class="news-header__wrapper news-header__summary">Tolle neue Kleidung im Künstlerstil, zu färbende Möbel, Schädel zum Sammeln und VIELES MEHR im Hotel zu unserem neuen Event! </p>
    </article>
    <article class="news-header news-header--column">
        <a href="/community/article/25320/habboevents-im-juni-3" class="news-header__link news-header__banner">
            <figure class="news-header__viewport">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_gen15_04.png" alt="HabboEvents im Juni" class="news-header__image news-header__image--featured">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_gen15_04_thumb.png" alt="HabboEvents im Juni" class="news-header__image news-header__image--thumbnail">
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="/community/article/25320/habboevents-im-juni-3" class="news-header__link news-header__wrapper">
            <h2 class="news-header__title">HabboEvents im Juni</h2>
        </a>
        <aside class="news-header__wrapper news-header__info">
            <time class="news-header__date">03.06.2019</time>
        </aside>
        <p class="news-header__wrapper news-header__summary">Hier findest du alle Events, die im Monat Juni stattfinden werden!</p>
    </article>
    <article class="news-header news-header--column">
        <a href="/community/article/25281/der-tempel-der-ahnen" class="news-header__link news-header__banner">
            <figure class="news-header__viewport">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_playhab_newDE.png" alt="Der Tempel der Ahnen" class="news-header__image news-header__image--featured">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_playhab_newDE_thumb.png" alt="Der Tempel der Ahnen" class="news-header__image news-header__image--thumbnail">
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="/community/article/25281/der-tempel-der-ahnen" class="news-header__link news-header__wrapper">
            <h2 class="news-header__title">Der Tempel der Ahnen</h2>
        </a>
        <aside class="news-header__wrapper news-header__info">
            <time class="news-header__date">02.06.2019</time>
            <ul class="news-header__categories">
                <li class="news-header__category">
                    <a href="/community/category/fansites" class="news-header__category__link" translate="NEWS_CATEGORY_FANSITES">Fanseiten</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <p class="news-header__wrapper news-header__summary">Die PlayHab Nachrichten Redaktion berichtet:</p>
    </article>
    <article class="news-header news-header--column">
        <a href="/community/article/25272/bewerbungsrunden-fur-juli-2" class="news-header__link news-header__banner">
            <figure class="news-header__viewport">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_gen15_66.png" alt="[HE] Bewerbungsrunden für Juli" class="news-header__image news-header__image--featured">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_gen15_66_thumb.png" alt="[HE] Bewerbungsrunden für Juli" class="news-header__image news-header__image--thumbnail">
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="/community/article/25272/bewerbungsrunden-fur-juli-2" class="news-header__link news-header__wrapper">
            <h2 class="news-header__title">[HE] Bewerbungsrunden für Juli</h2>
        </a>
        <aside class="news-header__wrapper news-header__info">
            <time class="news-header__date">31.05.2019</time>
        </aside>
        <p class="news-header__wrapper news-header__summary">Es ist Zeit, dein Event für die HabboEvents im Juli anzumelden.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="news-header news-header--column">
        <a href="/community/article/25278/botschafterprojekt-juni-2019" class="news-header__link news-header__banner">
            <figure class="news-header__viewport">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_gen_amb_1.png" alt="Botschafterprojekt Juni 2019" class="news-header__image news-header__image--featured">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/lpromo_gen_amb_1_thumb.png" alt="Botschafterprojekt Juni 2019" class="news-header__image news-header__image--thumbnail">
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="/community/article/25278/botschafterprojekt-juni-2019" class="news-header__link news-header__wrapper">
            <h2 class="news-header__title">Botschafterprojekt Juni 2019</h2>
        </a>
        <aside class="news-header__wrapper news-header__info">
            <time class="news-header__date">30.05.2019</time>
            <ul class="news-header__categories">
                <li class="news-header__category">
                    <a href="/community/category/ambassadors" class="news-header__category__link" translate="NEWS_CATEGORY_AMBASSADORS">Botschafter</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <p class="news-header__wrapper news-header__summary">Botschafter Bewerbungsrunden</p>
    </article>
    <article class="news-header news-header--column">
        <a href="/community/article/25268/the-great-escape" class="news-header__link news-header__banner">
            <figure class="news-header__viewport">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/HabboNews_Promo.png" alt="The Great Escape" class="news-header__image news-header__image--featured">
                <img src="https://images.habbo.com/web_images/habbo-web-articles/HabboNews_Promo_thumb.png" alt="The Great Escape" class="news-header__image news-header__image--thumbnail">
            </figure>
        </a>
        <a href="/community/article/25268/the-great-escape" class="news-header__link news-header__wrapper">
            <h2 class="news-header__title">The Great Escape</h2>
        </a>
        <aside class="news-header__wrapper news-header__info">
            <time class="news-header__date">25.05.2019</time>
            <ul class="news-header__categories">
                <li class="news-header__category">
                    <a href="/community/category/fansites" class="news-header__category__link" translate="NEWS_CATEGORY_FANSITES">Fanseiten</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
        <p class="news-header__wrapper news-header__summary">Gibt es ein Entkommen?</p>
    </article>
    ...
```

The result is the source without the output of the javascript files.
Do you have any idea how to parse the page after all the javascript file has loaded your results?

Comment: Use the available RSS feed.

Comment: The RSS feed shows only the news but not other content. In addition, the RSS feed contains only the titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to do kind of page content scraping on client browser. You have options which may be chosen to do at the server side. Scraping a heavy javascript web page often needs our app (in this case at server side) to control a browser to render complete page firstly by waiting for a timeout duration, then read the rendered content for parsing necessary information.

- If you prefer PHP, Selenium with its [PHP's driver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) may be an option.
- Or if you prefer Javascript on NodeJS, lot of options but [this article](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/scrapping-the-content-of-single-page-application-spa-with-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-d040025f752b) may be a good reference for you. Where they guide to use [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) (to control browser for rending complete page) and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) (to parse the page content with ease) for solution.